# Discrete Mathematics Big-O notation Algorithm Complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, complexity-theory, big-o

I can probably figure out part b if you can help me do part a. I've been looking at this and similar problems all day, and I'm just having problems grasping what to do with nested loops. For the first loop there are n iterations, for the second there are n-1, and for the third there are n-1.. Am I thinking about this correctly?

Consider the following algorithm,
which takes as input a sequence of n integers a1, a2, ..., an
and produces as output a matrix M = {mij}
where mij is the minimum term
in the sequence of integers ai, a + 1, ..., aj for j >= i and mij = 0 otherwise.

initialize M so that mij = ai if j >= i and mij = 0

```
for i:=1 to n do
    for j:=i+1 to n do
        for k:=i+1 to j do
            m[i][j] := min(m[i][j], a[k])
        end
    end
end
return M = {m[i][j]}
```

(a) Show that this algorithm uses Big-O(n^3) comparisons to compute the matrix M.
(b) Show that this algorithm uses Big-Omega(n^3) comparisons to compute the matrix M.

Using this face and part (a), conclude that the algorithm uses Big-theta(n^3) comparisons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In part A, you need to find an upper bound for the number of `min` ops.

In order to do so, it is clear that the above algorithm has **less** `min` ops then the following:

```
for i=1 to n
  for j=1 to n //bigger range then your algorithm
    for k=1 to n //bigger range then your algorithm
        (something with min)
```

The above has **exactly** n^3 `min` ops - thus in your algorithm, there are *less* then `n^3` min ops.

From this we can conclude: `#minOps <= 1 * n^3` (for each n > 10, where 10 is arbitrary).

 By [definition of Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), this means the algorithm is `O(n^3)`

You said you can figure B alone, so I'll let you try it :)

---

hint: the middle loop has *more* iterations then `for j=i+1 to n/2`

Comment: Thanks! That makes much more sense than any of the other examples from the textbook. Now, for part b. Looking at your hint, if i only look at the first half of the terms, the number of operations would be less, but the algorithm would still carry out Cn^3 operations, where C <=1. Hence, the algorithm is Big-Omega(n^3). Is that correct?

Comment: @helmeplease: The idea is correct, but there are more steps that should be done to show it then so straight forward if you need it formally. Give it a try, use the same approach I used to show the big-O and after a few trials I'm sure you'll get there.

Comment: Would I have to say exactly how many operations this new algorithm has, or can I say "Cn^3 operations, where C <=1?" This is what I'm having the biggest problem with - calculating the number of operations when it's not as straightforward as in the example you gave.

Comment: If you can show some aribitrary `C*n^3`, it is OK- but you need to give a *specific* `C` and show why this `C` is correct. If you can *prove* "there exists such `C`" is also fine.

Comment: How would I show this for an arbitrary C*n^3, if I don't know the exact number of operations in my algorithm? I can't be 100% sure that minOps >= C*n^3 for an arbitrary C, can I?

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration of outer loop inner two nested loop would give `n^2` complexity if `i == n`. Outer loop will run for `i = 1 to n`. So total complexity would be a series like: `1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + ... ... ... + n^2`. This summation value is `n(n+1)(2n+1)/6`. Ignoring lower order terms of this summation term ultimately the order would be `O(n^3)`